# Como guardar vários valores em uma variável?

Tags: php

Estou criando um sistema com vários produtos, e neles vai ter um link, assim:

```
<a href ="verificar.php?valor=20">Imagem</a>
```

O arquivo ( `verificar.php` ) vai receber por `$_GET` o valor da variável ( `valor` ) que no exemplo é `20`.

Minha dúvida é: como guardar esse valor em uma variável, pois vai ter vários produtos, e ao clicar neles vai ter que guardar o valor e somar eles no final...

Posso usar o array? É possível me mostrar um exemplo de código?

Comment: Quando é que você faz a chamada ajax? click a click ou todos juntos? ou tem uma `form` que é submetida com todos os valores?

Comment: Pelo que você diz, será necessário usar um array na Session. Você já está usando Session?

Comment: Você terá que somar os valores primeiro, recomendo utilizando javascript, para apenas depois de concluir a soma, poder passar como parâmetro o valor total para a `verificar.php`

Comment: A sua pergunta está pouco clara, se explicar melhor como funciona o seu código e colocar aqui um exemplo do HTML de um produto, vai ser possivel responder à sua pergunta. Por enquanto está muito vago...

Comment: @PauloRoberto É um perigo somar tudo via JS e só passar o valor para o servidor! Se alguém abre um console do Chrome, pode facilmente fazer uma compra de um milhão custar $1. O ideal seria passar o id de cada produto e quantidades, e fazer os cálculos no servidor

Comment: Mas isto é um sistema de compras online?!

Comment: @bfavaretto obviamente o valor seria conferido no php né cara

Comment: @PauloRoberto Obviamente pra você e pra mim. Para o autor da pergunta, não sabemos... Ele precisa esclarecer várias coisas para que a pergunta possa receber uma resposta precisa.

Comment: tens razão @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2):

Você pode guardar a soma na session, assim toda vez que alguém clicar no link para a página verifica.php, o valor da variável "valor" vai ser acrescido a uma outra variável "valor total", guardada na session.

***verifica.php***

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['valor_total'] += $_GET['valor'];

echo $_SESSION['valor_total'];
```

[PHP Func. session_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php)
[PHP  Sessions - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Evite utlizar referencia do w3schools, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/692/w3schools-e-uma-referencia-horrivel-certo

http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: +1 Apesar da fonte ser dúbia, o conteúdo está correcto

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar vários valores para a mesma variável usando parenteses retos []. Isso faz o PHP guardar os valores num array.

```
<a href ="verificar.php?valor[]=20&valor[]=30">Imagem</a>
```

O PHP receberá em $_GET['valor'] o array array('20', '30');

Answer (score 2):

Bem, sem saber mais informação é difícil perceber o que pretende.

> Como guardar vários valores em uma variável?

Usando uma array(matriz) ou um objecto.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c'); //Array

//Objecto
$obj = new StdClass(); 
$obj->foo = 'bar';
$obj->baz = 'bazinga';
```

> Estou criando um sistema com vários produtos,(...)
>   Minha dúvida é: como guardar esse valor em uma variável, pois vai ter vários produtos, e ao clicar neles vai ter que guardar o valor e somar eles no final...

Parece estar a querer fazer um carrinho de compras.

Pelo que mostra, se não existe nenhum javascript por trás, o seu link vai provocar um redireccionamento da página. Para evitar isto tem de usar **AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML)** em PT -> "Javascript Assíncrono e XML"

---

### Código Exemplo

Uma forma relativamente simples de fazer um carrinho compras numa única página pode ser a seguinte:

> carrinho.php

```
<?php
class Producto {
    public $id;
    public $nome;
    public $preco;
    public $quantidade = 0;

    public function __construct($id, $preco, $nome, $quantidade = 0) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->preco = $preco;
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->quantidade = $quantidade;
    }

    public function adicionar($quantidade = 1) {
        $this->quantidade = $this->quantidade + $quantidade;
    }

    public function remover($quantidade = 1) {
        $this->quantidade = $this->quantidade - $quantidade;
        if ($this->quantidade < 0)
            $this->quantidade = 0;
    }
}

class Carrinho implements IteratorAggregate {

    public $productosNoCarrinho = array();

    public function __construct ($listaDeProductos){
        $this->productosNoCarrinho = $listaDeProductos;
    }

    public function adicionar($id, $quantidade = 1) {
        if (!isset($this->productosNoCarrinho[$id]))
            return false;

        $this->productosNoCarrinho[$id]->adicionar($quantidade);
        return true;
    }

    public function remover($id, $quantidade = 1) {
        if (!isset($this->productosNoCarrinho[$id]))
            return false;

        $this->productosNoCarrinho[$id]->remover($quantidade);
        return true;
    }

    public function total() {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->productosNoCarrinho as $prod) {
            $total += $prod->preco * $prod->quantidade;
        }
        return $total;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->productosNoCarrinho);
    }

    public function mostrar() {
        $html = "<table><tr><td>#</td><td>Producto</td><td>Preco</td></tr>";
        foreach ($this->productosNoCarrinho as $producto) {
            if ($producto->quantidade > 0) {
                $html .= "<tr><td>{$producto->quantidade}</td>".
                "<td>{$producto->nome}</td>".
                "<td>".$producto->preco * $producto->quantidade."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        $html .= "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>".$this->total()."</td></tr>";
        $html .= "</table>";
        return $html;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->mostrar();
    }
}

$listaDeProductos = array( 
    'A1' => new Producto('A1', 499, 'iPad air'),
    'A2' => new Producto('A2', 600, 'iPhone 5S'),
    'A3' => new Producto('A3', 1200, 'MacBook pro'),
    'A4' => new Producto('A4', 1100, 'iMac')
);

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {
    $_SESSION['carrinho'] = new Carrinho($listaDeProductos);
}

$carrinho = $_SESSION['carrinho'];

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'add' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $carrinho->adicionar($_GET['id']);
    } else if ($_GET['action'] == 'remove' && isset($_GET['id'])) { 
        $carrinho->remover($_GET['id']);
    }
    //print $carrinho->mostrar();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lista-de-productos">
<h1>Productos</h1>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($listaDeProductos as $prod) { ?>
        <li class="producto"
                data-id="<?=$prod->id?>"
                data-preco="<?=$prod->preco?>"
                data-nome="<?=$prod->nome?>"
        >
        <?=$prod->nome?> [<?=$prod->preco?>&euro;]
        <button class="adicionar">+</button>
        <button class="remover">-</button>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>    
</div>
<hr>
<h1>Carrinho</h1>
<div id="carrinho">
<?=$carrinho?>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var carrinhoID = $(this).attr("data-carrinhoID");

        $(document).on("click", ".producto .adicionar", function() {
            var prodID = $(this).parent().attr("data-id");
            $("#carrinho").load("carrinho.php?action=add&id=" +prodID +" #carrinho", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                //Sucesso
            });
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".producto .remover", function() {
            var prodID = $(this).parent().attr("data-id");
            $("#carrinho").load("carrinho.php?action=remove&id=" +prodID +" #carrinho", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                //Sucesso
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Explicando o código...

O que este código faz é criar um Carrinho (object da classe Carrinho) na sessão. O controlo do carrinho (e do preço e total a pagar) é feito pelo servidor mas a acção de adicionar e remover é feita pelo cliente (browser) por intermédio de AJAX.

Em termos de lógica, o que acontece é o seguinte:

1. O utilizador entra na página http://exemplo.com/carrinho.php(o *Browser* manda um pedido GET para o servidor)
2. O *Servidor* recebe o pedido e vê que, nos headers, não foi passado nenhum Cookie de sessão.
3. O *Servidor* cria uma sessão para o utilizador e manda-lhe um SetCookie nos headers
4. O *Browser* recebe e guarda o Cookie.
5. O utilizador adiciona um producto ao carrinho
6. O *Browser* envia um pedido GET Assincrono (AJAX) ao servidor, para a mesma página, mas com parâmetros no URL ((http://exemplo.com/carrinho.php?action=add&id=XX) com a accao a realizar e o id do producto. Também envia o Cookie que recebeu da primeira ves que o utilizador acedeu à página
7. O *Servidor* carrega o carrinho guardado na sessão, lê o pedido e percebe que tem de adicionar +1 na quantidade do producto XX no carrinho
8. O *Servidor* envia a página toda de volta
9. O *Browser* recebe o pedido mas em vez de mostrar a página toda, retira só a parte que está dentro da div id="carrinho"
   10 ...

O VERBO HTTP usado é o GET, mas podia ser o POST (aliás, fazia mais sentido). No entanto, assim é mais simples de visualizar.

### ATENÇÃO: Este código é só para fins de demonstração. **NÃO DEVE SER USADO EM PRODUÇÃO** pois é **INSEGURO**.