# Falha ao criar sistema de login

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de login em PHP que verifica duas condições.

1ª Se foi digitado login ou senha errada;
2ª Se foi digitado o URL direto.

A primeira verificação está correta. Estou tendo problema na segunda condição. Quando eu digito o login e a senha correta, o sistema redireciona para a pagina de acesso negado.

```
<?php 

   session_start();
   if(
      empty($_SESSION['login']) and empty($_SESSION['senha']) 
   )
   {
      unset($_SESSION['login']); 
      unset($_SESSION['senha']);
      header('location:acessonegado.php'); 
      exit;
   }

   $logado = $_SESSION['login'];    

?>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y3eE/)

A página index é a página de login.

Se o login estiver correto, redireciona para `questionario_pos_venda.php`. Senão, redireciona para `acesso_negado.php`.

No *head* do `questionario_pos_venda.php` tem a verificação se o login e a senha estão vazios. Se estiver `true`, vai redicionar para `acessonegado.php`.

Eu tenho `acesso_negado.php` e `acessonegado.php` porque tenho que exibir informações diferentes.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é um erro específico do usuário que não irá contribuir com outros usuários do site

Comment: O JSFiddle não está abrindo aqui (de novo), mas também como não entendo o porquê de uma dúvida sobre PHP precisar dele, tanto faz. Discordo parcialmente do comentário acima. Apesar de sim, ser um problema específico do usuário, solucionando esse problema o *knowledge base* seria ampliado. Porém, dada a solução apresentada, eu caracterizaria esse problema como uma **duplicata**. Bastaria apenas um link de referência.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como guardar vários valores em uma variável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3808/como-guardar-v%c3%a1rios-valores-em-uma-vari%c3%a1vel). Não é exatamente esse o problema, mas foi o mais próximo que pude encontrar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resolvi. `$_SESSION` está vindo vazio porque eu esqueci do `session_start();` no incio do **questionario_pos_venda.php**.

Comment: Marque sua própria resposta como melhor resposta. Sua dúvida hoje pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã.

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoAugusto